# Making the switch to managed solutions - impossible?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

My organization has been using an unmanaged solution approach for our in-house customizations for the longest time, using one big solution which contains all customizations. Microsoft has been pushing the concept of using managed solutions for all downstream environments, and using solution segmentation. So we are looking into making the switch. For existing customizations, simply trying to import the managed solution after deleting the unmanaged one does not seem to work.

`##[error]Solution import Failed. Error: A managed solution cannot overwrite the EntityRelationshipRole component  with Id=1ae98e99-f14e-e911-a963-000d3ab6d103 which has an unmanaged base instance.  The most likely scenario for this error is that an unmanaged solution has installed a new unmanaged EntityRelationshipRole component on the target system, and now a managed solution from the same publisher is trying to install that same EntityRelationshipRole component as managed.  This will cause an invalid layering of solutions on the target system and is not allowed.`

Other threads about this error say to delete and recreate the offending component in the destination instance. That approach doesn't seem possible for us though, as we're already in production for a long time. The error would probably appear for each and every component we have ever created. Is there no easy way to make the switch from unmanaged to managed for existing deployments?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @CoreyO'Brien Sadly, I have not been able to find a simple solution for this yet.

Comment: I have crossposted the question to the [Dynamics Community Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/418176/making-the-switch-to-managed-solutions---impossible), maybe we'll get an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is importing the managed solution using a few custom options:

```cs
var request = new ImportSolutionRequest
{
    ConvertToManaged = true,
    OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations = true
};

organizationService.Execute(request);
```